# Android: Pull HTML and Process it

Tags: android

I used a webview to get HTML for a site I want to pull info from but have no access to the website (server-side, only client side).

I'm able to pull the html via javascript. But when I run my code, my data field is not updated because it loads before my Javascript is finished. I want to process the data afterwards via JSOUP. Getting in with HTTPCLient is difficult because it is a website with a LOGIN, and it is SSL secured. I can get in via WebView(manual login) and then pull the data afterwards.

Is there a way to get or past the login, or to wait in the second thread until it has loaded all the html data?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView data;
Button getRost;
WebView webview;
String code;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvData);
    getRost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btGet);
    getRost.setOnClickListener(this);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvWeb);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btGet:
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "HtmlViewer");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                        "('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
            }

        });

        webview.loadUrl("URLTHATCONTAINTSINFO");
        data.setText(code); 
    }   


}
class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    private Context ctx;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public void showHTML(String html) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).setTitle("HTML").setMessage(html)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();
        code = html;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the site is using a self-signed certificate, you should be able to create your own SSL client and, provided you can see what is sent to the site to handle the login, send it along via a POST.

If it is using a full SSL certificate, then just POST the data...

Either way, have the webview process the results from there.

Example:

```
private void launchWeb() {
    webview = new WebView(this);

    // Where myWebview is the WebView object

    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    webview.clearCache(true);
    webview.clearHistory();
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

    String postData = "username=" + _username + "&password=" + _password;

    webview.postUrl("https://blahblah.com/somepath",
            EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));

}
```

Comment: Ok. Still leaves the second problem, javascript injection takes longer than initial thread.

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading what you're doing.  I thought you were trying to do something with the results from the site so you are trying to grab the code.  If that's the case: in your webview could you Override OnPageFinished and grab the source?

Comment: No, I need the source of the site I'm grabbing with Webview. I tried grabbing it with the Httpclient but that isn't working. I can't just grab it with the client because it's behind a login. Maybe I could combine the two, first post it via a WebView and then grab it with a HttpConnection, but do does two interact?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.  Launch your site (I posted the code to do that) and use your webview to process the login.  In your webview, Override the OnPageFinish method so when the login has completed you'll be notified via the callback.  Then you can access the source of the page.  You'll also be logged in and can use loadUrl to change pages.

Comment: OK I'll check tommorow if it is working, I'm still wondering if i Login with the Webview and I setup a new HTTPCLIENT it will still be logged in? Or it reverts to not logged in mode, cause I'm accessing a different address. One for login in, one for viewing data...

Comment: I guess that will depend on the server and how it determines the login (cookie, ip, etc.).  Good luck.